# Extracting data from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am using Caldera forms to store data on my WordPress site. When I save data for multiple choices (checkboxes) I get an array of data which is similar to following;

```
{"opt905217":"Option 1","opt2347462":"Option 2","opt905265":"Option 3","opt906845":"Option 4",}
```

How can I achiveve the following;

```
<ul>
<li>Option 1</li>
<li>Option 2</li>
<li>Option 3</li>
<li>Option 4</li>
</ul>
```

I tried using explode. But the problem is I have to skip the option IDs (e.g. `opt2347462`)

How can I get a list of **only the option values**?

Comment: u can't explode

Comment: u converting array to string so you must use implode function

Comment: its json value???

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<li>".$value."</li>"
}
```

And if your array is a json, first `json_decode($array, true)`

Comment: the correct symbol for key/value in foreach is `=>`

Answer (score 0):

As I see that you have JSON data.

```
$json = '{"opt905217":"Option 1","opt2347462":"Option 2","opt905265":"Option 3","opt906845":"Option 4",}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'opt905217'}; // Option 1
```

**Few Points to remember:**

- json_decode requires the string to be a valid json else it will
  return NULL.
- In the event of a failure to decode, json_last_error() can be used to
  determine the exact nature of the error.
- Make sure you pass in utf8 content, or json_decode may error out and
  just return a NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$abc = '{"opt905217":"Option 1","opt2347462":"Option 2","opt905265":"Option 3","opt906845":"Option 4"}';
$newarray = json_decode($abc,true); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach($newarray as $key => $value){ ?>
    <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
<?php }?>


</ul>
```

[link](https://eval.in/704580)